# Swagger generating curl request without escaping single quote character

Tags: curl, spring-boot, swagger-ui

We have configured rest endpoint through swagger and we have parameter named **temp** whose **parameterType** is set to query and **dataType** is set to string.This parameter is consuming string with single quote character for example its value can be dateTime:['abc'..'bcd']. So problem we are facing with generation of curl request without escaping single quote character in Curl block.However other characters are properly url encoded but for single quote character encoding is not happening. Following are maven coordinates of swagger-ui dependency

```
 <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Comment: @Helen single quote should be url encoded to '%27' that will solve my problem. That is not currently happening

Comment: You might want to [open an issue](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-ui/issues) in the Swagger UI repo.